# vuex clear persistent state only once in a pwa

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex, release

i have a setup where i was using the [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) module to save user settings inside my localStorage.

Now i want to wipe the localStorage only once for the next release. it should be a one time thing to be sure that all users have a clean localStorage for the next release.
instead of telling all users to clear there caches manually i am searching for a way to do it automatically.

my own idea was to use my PWA "Update Available" feature, which triggers the PWA serviceWorker to cache the application and then should do a `localStorage.clear()` once but that's not working somehow.

the localStorage will not be cleared with that try, all the old data still exists on users machines.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your app version in the localStorage.
Then, when they launch your app, you can compare the current version value (in the JS) with the version value they have in the storage. If it's different, ten you call `localStorage.clear()` automatically

Answer (score 1):

One alternative I would do is to call an `api` for version compare.
If the client's version is < than the server stated version.
Then call `localStorage.clear()`.